# Tone mapping shader OpenGL

Tags: opengl, mapping, textures, shader, hdr

I'm trying to implement tone mapping to an HDR image in OpenGL.

Previously, I make manual mip mapping of HDR image, to get a 1x1 texture (`RGBA32F` format) with the average value of luminance.

I find an example of tone mapping function and put it on my fragment shader.

In my render code,I have on `GL_TEXTURE0` the HDR image (format `GL_RGBA32F`), on `GL_TEXTURE1` the 1x1 texture with average value.

The LDR texture (`RGBA8` format) where I want to render, is allocated in a FrameBuffer (fboTN) on `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`.

I use FreeImage library to upload the HDR image (OpenEXR format).

Here's the code:

```
void toneMapping(){
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboTN);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  // Set viewport and textures

  setMVP();
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); HDRtex->bind();     // Source HDR tex
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); DSavgTex0->bind();  // 1x1 tex with avgLum
  toneMappingShad->bind();
    float key = 0.18f, Ywhite = 1e6f, sat = 1.0f;
    toneMappingShad->setUniformValue1f("key", key);
    toneMappingShad->setUniformValue1f("Ywhite", Ywhite);
    toneMappingShad->setUniformValue1f("sat", sat);
    toneMappingShad->setUniformValue("width", im->getWidth());
    toneMappingShad->setUniformValue("height", im->getHeight());
    toneMappingShad->setUniformValue4f("MVP", glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    drawQuad(toneMappingShad);
  toneMappingShad->unbind();
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); DSavgTex0->unbind();    // 1x1 tex with avgLum
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); HDRtex->unbind();   // Source HDR tex
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

// RENDER CODE
toneMapping();
texShad->bind();
    texShad->setUniformValue4f("MVP", glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    LDRtex->bind();
    drawQuad(texShad);
    LDRtex->unbind();
texShad->bind();
```

My output is almost black screen ( I can guess the quad I draw).
`texShad` shaders are very simple; just draws texture on screen.

I'm going to show tone mapping shaders:

Here is the vertex shader (simple):

```
#version 420

in vec2 vUV;
in vec4 vVertex;
uniform int width;  // size of texture
uniform int height;
smooth out vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform mat4 MVP;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = MVP*vVertex;
  vTexCoord = vec2(vUV.x*width,vUV.y*height);
}
```

And the fragment:

```
#version 420

uniform float key;
uniform float Ywhite;
uniform float sat;
layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D hdrSampler;     // HDR texture
layout(binding=1) uniform sampler2D downSampler;    // Texture 1x1 with average of luminance
smooth in vec2 vTexCoord;           
layout(location=0) out vec4 color;  // LDR sample output (tone mapped image)

const mat3 RGB2XYZ = mat3(0.4124, 0.3576, 0.1805,
                           0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722,
                           0.0193, 0.1192, 0.9505);


vec3 tonemap(vec3 RGB, float logAvgLum){
    vec3 XYZ = RGB2XYZ * RGB;
    float Y = (key / logAvgLum) * XYZ.y;
    float Yd = (Y * (1.0 + Y /(Ywhite * Ywhite))) / (1.0 + Y);
    return pow(RGB / XYZ.y, vec3(sat,sat,sat)) * Yd;
}   


void main(){
    vec3 hdr = texture(hdrSampler, vTexCoord).rgb;
    float logAvgLum = exp(texture(downSampler,vec2(0.0,0.0)).a);
    color.rgb = tonemap(hdr, logAvgLum);
}
```

If I put something like `color.a = X` output doesn't change.

One important doubt: is correct this (`texture(downSampler,vec2(0.0,0.0)).a`) to get the average value? I don't know if `0,0` are the correct value coords to get, because it's 1x1 the size of the texture.

I have spent a lot of time with this, but I can't see what's wrong.

Here's the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: What is the point of the following code? `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2); LDRtex->bind(); // Output LDR tex`. If you are trying to *output* to a texture, binding it to a Texture Image Unit is unimportant (that is for *sampling* textures). You need to attach the texture's image to your Framebuffer Object as a color attachment. I assume you already know this, but I do not see any part of your code or description that talks about actually doing this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I made a mistake pasting the code; I took other older version of one piece of code. I'm going to post the correct tone-mapping code.